# hadoop-mongodb driver and mahout

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mahout

I have setup hadoop on top of mongodb using hadoop-mongodb driver.
Currently I can successfully output results from a M/R job to a mongo colection.
I would like to use mahout to take advantage of some of the provided algorithms. 
Is it possible to use mahout on top of mongodb and output directly to a mongo collection? 
Is there a how to or a sample I can read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it is nothing directly to do with Mahout. You specify your input and output URLs in a way that selects your MongoDB locations. The rest is a matter of Hadoop-Mongo integration and setup.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am wondering if there is a tutorial I can follow because in all the sample code I have found mahout is using the file system.